# Mobile First Platform + ionic( Android Platform) Error : IBM WebSphere Application Server Context Root Not Found

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ibm-mobilefirst, mfp

Ionic android app after connecting to MobileFirst server make a request in HTTP protocol as below,

**POST /mfp/api/adapters/SCAppMiddleWare/apiCall HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: WLNativeAPI(hwALE-H; ALE-L21C636B571; ALE-L21; SDK 23; Android 6.0)
Authorization: Bearer 
x-wl-analytics-tracking-id: 51110d67-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXXX
x-mfp-analytics-metadata: {"deviceID":"4088fcd7-XXX-XXXX-XXXX-0c888fb82c6c","os":"android","clientID":"XXXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-f7ccbe388f32","osVersion":"6.0","brand":"Huawei","model":"ALE-L21","mfpAppName":"com.XXXXXX.XXXXXX.XXXXXX.test","mfpAppVersion":"0.9.9","appVersionDisplay":"0.9.9","appVersionCode":"909","appStoreId":"com.XXX.XXX","appStoreLabel":"XXX+XXX"}
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 384
Host: devmfp.XXX.XX:9080
Connection: Keep-Alive
Accept-Encoding: gzip**

and this error comes with the response :

**HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
X-Powered-By: Servlet/3.0
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Mon, 29 Jan 2018 04:51:45 GMT
Content-Length: 777
Connection: Close
{"statusReason":"Not Found",
"responseHeaders":{"Connection":"Close","Content-Length":"29092","Date":"Mon, 29 Jan 2018 04:51:44 GMT","Content-Type":"text/html; charset: UTF-8"},"isSuccessful":false,"responseTime":17,"totalTime":21,"warnings":[],
"errors":["IBM WebSphere Application Server         Context Root Not Found     Licensed Materials - Property of IBM © Copyright IBM Corp. 1997, 2013.  All Rights Reserved.  IBM, and the IBM logo are trademarks or registered trademarks of International Business Machines Corp., registered in many jurisdictions worldwide. Other product and service names might be trademarks of IBM or other companies. A current list of IBM trademarks is available on the Web at  Copyright and trademark information ."],"info":[],"statusCode":404}**

Need to identify what could cause this issue, and how to fix it :) . App and Adapters have been deployed without any issue according to the tutorial https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/6.3/hybrid-tutorials/.

Answer (score 1):

The error says `"statusCode":404` and `IBM WebSphere Application Server Context Root Not Found`.

This happens because you do not have the correct context root specified in your mfpclient.properties/plist. What version of MobileFirst are you using?
The tutorial link you have provided points to MobileFirst 6.3.
if you're using MobileFirst v8, the steps will be different.

Comment: Thanks for your quick feedback, It's MFP v8.

Comment: This is the doc you should look at https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/cordova-tutorials/